# How to fix NPCs flinging off map/falling apart

Tags: lua, roblox

I have just made a script that clones NPCs to random locations using the script below, but the NPC's do not appear at any of the spawn locations that I stated in my script, but in the middle of the actual map only. They also fall apart/fling off the map when cloned. Should I use a table to fix this? How to fix?

```
local module = {}

wavepause = game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.WavePauseLength.Value
trollanoid = game.ReplicatedStorage.Trollanoid
spawnpoints = workspace.Test1.Spawns:GetChildren()

function trollanoidsummon()
    local chosenspawn = spawnpoints[math.random(#spawnpoints)]
    local clone = trollanoid:Clone()
    clone.Parent = workspace.Zombies
    clone.UpperTorso.Position = chosenspawn.Position
end

module.Wave1 = function()
    wait(20)
    trollanoidsummon()
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
end

return module
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the CFrame of the HumanoidRootPart

```lua
function trollanoidsummon()
    local chosenspawn = spawnpoints[math.random(#spawnpoints)]
    local clone = trollanoid:Clone()
    clone.Parent = workspace.Zombies
    clone.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame= chosenspawn.CFrame
end
```

Comment: I tried it and now they just destroy themselves. The script and humanoid are still intact in the model.

Comment: CaptinLetus, Models also have the function SetPrimaryPartCFrame(). You could call `clone:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(chosenSpawn.CFrame)` to do this as well